# Why is my first image not clickable?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a square that contains pictures and each picture is supposed to be clickable to take you to that person's profile, but my top left picture is not clickable. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4HJb/1/) so you can see the problem.

```
<div id = 'crew_div'>
    <div class = 'my_crew'><div id = 'jason'><a href = 'http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/musicmakesmelosectrl/'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/jason.jpg' title = 'View Posts by Jason'></a></div></div>
    <div class = 'my_crew'><div id = 'dharam'><a href = 'http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/4everevolution/'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/dharam.png' title = 'View Posts by Dharam'></a></div></div>
    <div class = 'my_crew'><div id = 'james'><a href='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/jjstiles/'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/james.png' title = 'View Posts by James'></a></div></div>
    <div class = 'my_crew'><div id = 'cody'><a href='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/codecray/'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/Cody.jpg' title = 'View Posts by Cody'></a></div></div>
</div>
```

```
#crew_div {
    position:relative;
    width: 312px;
    height:312px;   
}

.my_crew {
    position:absolute;  
}

.my_crew img {
    width:156px;
    display:block;  
}

.my_crew #jason {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
}

.my_crew #dharam {
    top:0px;
    left:156px;
    position:relative;
}

.my_crew #james {
    top: 156px;
    left: 0px;  
    position:relative;
}

.my_crew #cody {
    top:156px;
    left:156px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified width/height dimensions or top/left positioning for your `<div class="my_crew">`. They are each positioned at the top-left, and their child `<div>` is then positioned relative to the absolutely positioned parent. That's why the top-left isn't clickable, because it's really stacked under 3 other `<div>`s.

A better solution would be to combine the two `<div>`s into one.

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/R4HJb/8/

```
<div id = 'crew_div'>
    <div class = 'my_crew jason'><a href = 'http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/musicmakesmelosectrl/'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/jason.jpg' title = 'View Posts by Jason'></a></div>
            <div class = 'my_crew dharam'><a href = 'http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/4everevolution/'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/dharam.png' title = 'View Posts by Dharam'></a></div>
            <div class = 'my_crew james'><a href='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/jjstiles/'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/james.png' title = 'View Posts by James'></a></div>
            <div class = 'my_crew cody'><a href='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/codecray/'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/Cody.jpg' title = 'View Posts by Cody'></a></div>
</div>

#crew_div {
    position:relative;
    width: 312px;
    height:312px;   
}

.my_crew {
    position:absolute;  
    width: 156px;
    height: 156px;
}

.my_crew img {
    width:156px;
    display:block;  
}

.my_crew.jason {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.my_crew.dharam {
    top:0px;
    left:156px;
}

.my_crew.james {
    top: 156px;
    left: 0px;  
}

.my_crew.cody {
    top:156px;
    left:156px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `z-index` to your image like this :

```
.my_crew #jason {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but do you know why just the jason div would need changed? Weird that the other ones worked fine

Comment: You haven't specified width/height dimensions or top/left positioning for your `<div class="my_crew">`. They are each positioned at the top-left, and their child `<div>` is then positioned relative to the absolutely positioned parent. That's why the top-left isn't clickable, because it's really stacked under 3 other `<div>`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need, I reorganized your HTML a bit :)

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5R49y/)

```
<div id = 'crew_div'>
<a href = 'http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/musicmakesmelosectrl/'><div class = 'my_crew'><div id = 'jason'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/jason.jpg' title = 'View Posts by Jason'></div></div></a>
        <a href = 'http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/4everevolution/'><div class = 'my_crew'><div id = 'dharam'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/dharam.png' title = 'View Posts by Dharam'></div></div></a>
        <a href='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/jjstiles/'><div class = 'my_crew'><div id = 'james'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/james.png' title = 'View Posts by James'></div></div></a>
        <a href='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/author/codecray/'><div class = 'my_crew'><div id = 'cody'><img src='http://www.startingtofeelit.com/profile/Cody.jpg' title = 'View Posts by Cody'></div></div></a>
```

Comment: This worked as well. Do you know why my code didn't work, for future reference?

Comment: Your image was _"hidden"_ under the div, so I made the entire div be clickable :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just float them next to each other? That will also save some lines of CSS.

```
.my_crew {
    float:left;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/T5LCm/